# Amazon like Ecommerce site and Recommendation system

Tags: social-networking, recommendation-engine

I am planning to implement a basic recommendation system that uses Facebook Connect or similar social networking site API's to connect a user's profile, do an analysis based on tags and use the results to generate item recommendations on my e-commerce site (works similar to Amazon).

I do believe I need to divide parts into such:

1. Fetching social networking data via
   API's.(Indeed user allows this)
2. Analyze these data and generate
       tokes.
3. By using information tokens, do item
       recommendations on my e-commerce
       site.

**EG:** I am a fan of "The Strokes" band on my Facebook account, system analyzes this and recommends me "The Strokes Live" CD.

For any part(fetching data, doing recommendation based on tags...), what algorithm and method would you recommend/ is used?

Comment: Is your ecommerce cite already live? It helps a lot if you already have data based on your users. Essentially you will want to train a model based on the idea that uses who bought x have these features(tags).  If no one has bought anything yet, its tough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being on your place I would definitely had a look at the algorithms and articles published during the [Netflix](http://www.netflixprize.com/) contest. See forum and the sites of the best teams.

Answer (score 8):

Good practical books on these kind of algorithms are:

- [Collective Intelligence in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988312), Satnam Alag, Manning, 2008, ISBN 1933988312
- [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988665), Haralambos Marmanis, Manning 2009, ISBN 1933988665
- [Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325),  Toby Segaran, O'Reilly Media 2007, ISBN 0596529325

Comment: Hey, if you wouldn't mind, please don't roll back your revisions to these posts - [we're trying to get rid of shortened URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup), not add more of them.